# Create buttons and actions programatically and dynamically

Tags: swift, xcode

Ok this question might be a bit difficult to comprehend... but thanks in advance.

Let's say I have a list with 3 entries in it, `["Example 1", "Example 2", "Example 3"]`

Let's also say I have another list, also with 3 entries in it. `["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"]`

Now the goal is to create a button, with an offset of +10x for each (to not have overlapping) each with its own action.

Now the problem lies with the fact that these 2 lists are not hardcoded, and are generated as the app runs.

I know how to create buttons programmatically, I know how to add actions programmatically, but only if I hard code them.

I need a way to iterate over these lists, creating a button for each entry, and an action for each entry.

I was trying something like this:

```
func create(id: String){ #Accepts an id as a parameter, this id will be used to name the action.
    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = (frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 60, y: 20, width: 50, height: 50)) #Currently does not change x coor
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.setTitle("Name your Button ", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(id), for: .touchUpInside)#Now this is where it fails, I cannot have id as the selector, as it does not exist, yet
    self.view.addSubview(button)

    func id(sender: UIButton!) { #Uses the id variable passed to the function to create a function.
            print("Button tapped")
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the above does not work, otherwise I wouldn't be here. Any help is appreciated.

TL;DR I have 2 lists, I want to iterate over the lists creating a button for each entry (I can do that part), and I want each button to have an action, but I cannot hardcode this as lists are generated while program runs.

Comment: Just use the UITableView & UITableViewCell apis. They're optimized for presenting some sort of UI based on a list datasource. Each of your lists can be a section, and you can have a button for each cell representing one of those list values.

Answer (score 3):

Don't attempt to use a different action for all of the buttons. Use the same (hard-coded) action method and, within that method's implementation, distinguish the buttons some other way. The obvious choice is to use the `tag` property of the buttons. When you create them, assign a meaningful value as the `tag`. In the action method, examine the `sender`'s `tag` and act accordingly.